# Matching line number in Google Death Test expectation

Tags: regex, googletest

I am trying to match a line number in death test but I can't get the regex to work.  The following works:

```
EXPECT_DEATH(run_test(), "70");
```

But the following doesn't:

```
EXPECT_DEATH(run_test(), "\\\\d\\\\d");
```

I get the this error in this case:

```
10: [ RUN      ] AgentErrorTest.DiesOnTimerCreateError
10: /home/edge/test/test_dispatcher_error.cc:119: Failure
10: Death test: run_test()
10:     Result: died but not with expected error.
10:   Expected: \\d\\d
10: Actual msg:
10: [  DEATH   ] src/dispatcher/dispatcher.cc:70 loop_sync(): MESSAGE=timer_create() error: Inappropriate ioctl for device PRIORITY=3 SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=test_dispatcher_error DEVICE_ID=my_device_id TASK_ID=?
10: [  DEATH   ] 
10: [  FAILED  ] AgentErrorTest.DiesOnTimerCreateError (244 ms)
```

I've tried various numbers of backslashes but nothing works.

When I use `MatchesRegex()`:

```
EXPECT_DEATH(run_test(), MatchesRegex("\\d+"));
```

I get a compile problem:

```
In file included from /usr/include/gtest/gtest-death-test.h:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/gtest/gtest.h:60,
                 from /usr/include/gmock/internal/gmock-internal-utils.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/gmock/gmock.h:58,
                 from /home/edge/test/test_dispatcher_error.cc:14:
/home/edge/test/test_dispatcher_error.cc: In member function 'virtual void {anonymous}::AgentErrorTest_DiesOnTimerCreateError_Test::TestBody()':
/home/edge/test/test_dispatcher_error.cc:111:47: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const testing::internal::RE&' from expression of type 'testing::PolymorphicMatcher<testing::internal::MatchesRegexMatcher>'
         EXPECT_DEATH( run_test(), MatchesRegex("\\d+"));
                                               ^
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe `MatchesRegex("\\d+")`

Comment: I get a compile error when I do that.